# Как в php переводить выполнение программы на внешний php файл

Tags: php

В коде ниже представлены поля: одно для регистрации, второе для входа на сайт. Как видно формы ссылаются на один и тот же файл(`action="html/My_page.php"`) - так как после что регистрации, что входа должны попадать на главную страницу.

```
<form action="html/My_page.php" method="POST">
    <label for="login">Имя пользователя</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" class="field" autocomplete="off" id="input_login">
    <label for="Password"><a href="#" onclick="return show_hide_password(this);">Пароль</a></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="field" id="input_password">
    <button class="registration">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
<form action="html/My_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="login" class="hidden" id="output_login">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="hidden" id="output_password">
    <button class="registration copying" id="login_btn">Войти</button>
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что так как обе формы ссылаются на один и тот же файл - выходит что в этот же файл я должен подключить php скрипт и для регистрации и для входа.
А именно `include "../html/Core/Input.php";` и `include "../html/Core/Loging.php";`.

```
<head>
    <?php
        include "../html/Core/Input.php";
        include "../html/Core/Loging.php";
        include "more_usable/head.php";
    ?>
</head>
```

Но в таком случае выполняться будут оба скрипта. Как заставить программу реагировать только соответствующий кнопке скрипт?

К примеру в Си есть возможность определить глобальные переменные в отдельном файле, и затем используя соответствующий этому файлу заголовочник, с помощью указателей на эти переменные управлять поведением программы. Как я понял из беглого гуглежа и просмотра документации в php нет ни заголовочников, ни указателей.

В общем мне бы знать или как программу заставить выполнить внешний скрипт без `include` и `require`, или же как влиять на переменные во внешних файлах также без `include` и `require` - так как после перехода к другому php файлу все изменения проведенные в значениях переменных попросту изчезают.

Comment: создайте два файла: registration.php & login.php - там реализуйте всё что надо и в формах соответственно вызывайте их

Comment: Так вы просто в формах передайте дополнительный параметр в скрытом инпуте. А в файле в зависимости от того, какой параметр получен -- подключайте нужный скрипт

Comment: @Виктор, но проблема в том что когда я вызывал сами эти формы, то у меня просто был белый экран в браузере, вместо нужной мне страницы

Comment: @rusgeli, вроде понял вас, попробую если что отпишусь) спасибо))

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman, а я только написал ответ для вас...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто в формах передайте дополнительный параметр в скрытом инпуте. А в файле в зависимости от того, какой параметр получен -- подключайте нужный скрипт

```
<form action="html/My_page.php" method="POST">
    <label for="login">Имя пользователя</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" class="field" autocomplete="off" id="input_login">
    <label for="Password"><a href="#" onclick="return show_hide_password(this);">Пароль</a></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="field" id="input_password">
    <input type="hidden" name="regLog" value="registration">
    <button class="registration">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
<form action="html/My_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="login" class="hidden" id="output_login">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="hidden" id="output_password">
    <input type="hidden" name="regLog" value="login">
    <button class="registration copying" id="login_btn">Войти</button>
</form>
```

```
<head>
    <?php
        if ($_POST['regLog'] == 'registration') include "../html/Core/Input.php";
        else if ($_POST['regLog'] == 'login') include "../html/Core/Loging.php";
        include "more_usable/head.php";
    ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Я это немного по другому представил, но ваш вариант мне нравится даже больше)))